# How do you share folder on a xubuntu with Samba?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, samba, sharing

I have a xubuntu 18.04 fresh install.

I installed `sudo apt-get install -y samba samba-common python-glade2 system-config-samba`

I added this to smb.conf :

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        server string = Samba Server %v
        netbios name = ubuntu
        security = user
        map to guest = bad user
        dns proxy = no

[dev]
        path=/home/sylvain/dev/
        writeable=yes
        browseable=yes
```

samba logs :

```
[2018/08/29 15:56:24.751911,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2018/08/29 15:59:01.798725,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
```

The xubuntu has access to the internet and I can ping it from a windows machine.

The machine is invisible for the windows machines. What can I do to enable shares?

Comment: There are no errors there.  What happens on the windows side? This may be more a windows problem than an ubuntu problem. Firewall? Same network ? See https://superuser.com/questions/570928/mapping-a-smb-share-in-windows

Comment: The Windows machines may use a different WORKGROUP name (I know, that rarely happens...)

Comment: You were right, SMB 1.0 is disabled by default on the current windows 10

Comment: Thx, I did not knew that there was anothere version

Comment: I'll stil allow SMB 1 it allows me to see the other windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by the question - or maybe the answers. Samba - the server part - will respond to any request from any client using the smb1 dialect all the way up to the smb3 dialect. It does that through a negotiation with the client. And it does so automatically.

Is the problem this:

> The machine is invisible for the windows machines. What can I do to
>   enable shares?

Run this command on your Linux machine to find the exact host name of your machine:

```
hostname
```

Go to Run ( WinKey+R ) on the Win10 machine and access that hostname with a ".local" at the end - as in:

```
\\xubuntu-host-name.local
```

Worst case access the samba server by its IP address:

```
\\192.168.0.100
```

You do not have to enable SMB1 on the Win10 client to access a Samba server but you will be required to access it explicitly by name since SMB1 controls netbios name browsing - or "discovery"

Comment: I did not knew that windows machine are no longer supposed to have discovery. It explains so many things.

Comment: Windows does have discovery using a different method called WS-Discovery which looks a lot like Avahi but not close enough for it to work with Linux. That's why when you disable SMB1 on the client side of Win10 it can still "discover" other Windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

try this code using terminal

```
sudo mount.cifs -o username=(windows user name) //(Windows PC IP)/(Windows share folder name) /(Ubuntu share folder path)
```

after that it will ask sudo password and then User password. for User Password you have to type Windows PC User password. and it will mount Windows shared folder in to your Ubuntu Shared folder. after that if you need to un-mount the shared folder you can follow

```
sudo umount -a -t cifs
```

code and it will un-mount windows shared folder from ubuntu folder. if it fails try

```
sudo umount -a -t cifs -1
```